# how to get rid of .goutputstream files

Tags: home-directory

I have many files with names like *.goutputstream-AAAAAA* in my home folder and I don't know why they've been created and how to get rid of them?
I usually delete them but they would appear again in days.

Comment: This is a well-known bug: [Bug #984785: .goutputstream files polluting $HOME](https://bugs.launchpad.net/ubuntu/+source/lightdm/+bug/984785)

Comment: This question has been closed because bugs are off-topic here. See the [FAQ].